# Dynamic parameter passing in angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I tried some code like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LqXrC/90/)

I need to dynamically pass parameter `{{sp.peType}}`  in `controller-name` in my code.

```
<div ng-repeat="sp in obj.PEs">{{sp.peType}}
   <div add-icons controller-name="{{sp.peType}}"></div>
</div>
```

in which my script code is like

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller("testCtrl", function($scope){
  $scope.obj = {
    "PEs": {
        "1": {
            "peId": "1",
            "peName": "Exp1",
            "peDisplayName": "Exp",
            "peType": "Exp",
            "peCategory": "PE"
        },
        "2": {
            "peId": "2",
            "peName": "RN1",
            "peDisplayName": "RNull",
            "peType": "RN",
            "peCategory": "PE"
        }
    }
 }
})

.directive('addIcons', function(){
return {
    restrict : 'A',
    scope:{},
    controller : "@",
    name:"controllerName"
  }
}).
controller("Exp",function($scope){
        alert("Exp Contorller")

}).
controller("RN",function($scope){
    alert("RN controller");

});
```

But this doesn't seems to work!

Getting this error

> Error: [ng:areq] Argument '{{sp.peType}}' is not a function, got
>   undefined

Any idea is Appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

it is because `PEs` is an object, not an array. change `PEs` to:

```
 "PEs": [
     {
        "peId": "1",
        "peName": "Exp1",
        "peDisplayName": "Exp",
        "peType": "Exp",
        "peCategory": "PE"
    },
    {
        "peId": "2",
        "peName": "RN1",
        "peDisplayName": "RNull",
        "peType": "RN",
        "peCategory": "PE"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I made [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utkh1acu/4/)

Why don't have a directive controller and pass the controller name as a directive parameter and do the whole logic inside of the directive controller?

HTML

```
<div add-icons controller-name="sp.peType"></div>
```

DIRECTIVE

```
.directive('addIcons', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        'controllerName': '='
    },
    controller: function($scope) {
        console.log($scope.controllerName);

        switch ($scope.controllerName) {
            case 'Exp':
                expControllerLogic();                    
                break;
            case 'RN':
                rnControllerLogic();
                break;
            default:                
                alert("Default");
        }   

        function expControllerLogic() {
            alert('Exp Controller');
        }

        function rnControllerLogic() {
            alert("RN controller");
        }
    }
}
});
```

Comment: can you create a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), It will be easier to assist you.

Comment: sorry this is not meant to be commented here